# How to control particle's direction by animation node?

Tags: animation-nodes

As title, i do not have any idea to control particle's direction by AN.

Comment: Use Force-field of type *Curve Guide*.

Comment: Are those particles from a particle system, or are they created in AN?

Comment: Made by particle system.

Comment: @EthanLiu Did you try Jaroslav's suggestion?

Comment: @OmarAhmad i know how to use curve guide force.
Just want to know is it possible to control particle by AN.

Comment: Oh, so you want to define the velocity/acceleration of the particles (Their direction and speed)? If so, unfortunately, there is no way to do that in AN. Blender doesn't allow it.

Comment: @OmarAhmad, thanks for your help.By the way, is it possible to control in the Everything Node in the future.

Comment: @EthanLiu Probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to alter the velocity or acceleration of particles of particle systems, the Blender python API doesn't allow it. However, if you want to control the general direction of particles, you can instance force fields and control their orientation and strength as suggested by  Jaroslav Jerryno. As an example, lets create a spiral spline in Animation Node and enable *Curve Guide Force Field* and *Path Animation* for it:

[image: Node Tree]

Or perhaps by animating a wind force field:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant. This is really useful creating fizzy drinks with all those bubbles.